# Can not center align text under icons in flex table

Tags: css, flexbox, icons

I've made this flexbox table like this:

```
<div class="flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col">
            <i class="thumbs-up"></i>                                            
             <i>20</i>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
            <i class="thumbs-down"></i>                                         
            <i>5</i>
        </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.thumbs-up {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  &:after {
    content: " ";
    background: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.5.6/collection/build/ionicons/svg/ios-arrow-up.svg) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}

.thumbs-down {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  &:after {
    content: " ";
    background: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.5.6/collection/build/ionicons/svg/ios-arrow-down.svg) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}


.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 20%;

}

.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;

    i {
        text-align: left;
    }

}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karlomn/2fpxj8Lm/7/).

As you can see the numbers are not quite center-aligned below the icons.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your numbers aren't center-aligned is because:

1. The `i` elements within `.flex-col` have the style `text-align: left` applied.
2. The `i` elements don't have a width set, so take up 100% of the parent element width (`.flex-col`)

So if you had aligned the text in the center, it would have been in the middle of the column, away from the icon.  I've added some debugging borders to elements on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ax2eLcmo/6/) to try and explain the issue.

To fix this I've added a width to the `i` element containing the numbers [example fiddle solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ax2eLcmo/5/)

An alternative solution would be to set `margin: right` on the `.flex-col` elements, removing `flex-basis` and `flex` style rules.  Then set `text-align: center` on the `i` element as above.
[see alternative  example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75p2tocw/1/)